# Using icons in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, icons, symbols

I want users to be able to post an icon/symbol (in example: ❤) in a form in HTML.
After getting back the input in PHP, the symbol still exists. Where it goes wrong is when I put in into the database, then it converts into some weird symbols. I know it is not a problem in the database, since I am able to input the icons into the database using a Minecraft Plugin. There I added basically
`?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the URI and it worked. How is this possible to do using PHP? I use the following code for the connection: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Thanks!

Comment: the first thing its not an ( ❤) icon

Comment: Please be sure that your database field be UTF8 character set.

Comment: The database field is utf8mb4_general_ci. I also tried utf8_unicode_ci, but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

function.

It's in literally first google result for

> mysqli character set

phrase.

Comment: At the moment I have the following, which does not work:

Comment: `// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
}`

Comment: Found the problem. Had `mysqli_set_charset("utf8",$conn);` instead of first `$conn`. Thanks!